# wrong URI passed through spring form action

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, request-mapping

my project is called CV; in a jsp I have the following spring:form action in the "anagrafica.jsp":

```
<form:form modelAttribute="anagrafica" action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/formazione/save" method="post">
```

in the controller I have:

```
package it.curriculum.controller;

@Transactional
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/anagrafica")
public class AnagraficaController {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;
    @Autowired
    private AnagraficaDao anagraficaDao;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showHome(@ModelAttribute("tecnologia")Tecnologia tecnologia, ModelMap map){
        map.addAttribute(context.getBean("anagrafica"));
        return "anagrafica";
    }

    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String validateAnag(@ModelAttribute("anagrafica") Anagrafica anagrafica, @ModelAttribute("formazione") Formazione formazione){
        anagraficaDao.save(anagrafica);
        return "formazione"
    }
}
```

the problem is when I click on the submit button of the anagrafica form:
it executes the code inside the previous controller and then it redirects to:

*localhost:8080/CV/formazione/save*
Why so?
I just wanted to be redirected to

*localhost:8080/CV/formazione*

not

*localhost:8080/CV/formazione/save*.
Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: put your entire code or enough to give you feedback

Comment: Is it wrong ? `@RequestMapping("/anagrafica")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `redirect` keyword / merchanism.

You need to redirect as follows,

```
@RequestMapping("/save"){
    ...
return "redirect:/formazione";
```

Comment: tried, same result: 404 and URL: http://localhost:8080/CV/formazione/save

Comment: @Fausto do you have relevant mapping to which you have redirect?

Comment: after your answer I noticed the steps between URLs where incorrect. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Change the request url on Class.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/formazione")
public class AnagraficaController {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;
    ....
```

Comment: thanks chaoluo but I need that requestMapping; there's a previous form that redirects to "anagrafica", if I delete that mapping the previous form action gives me 404 because there's no more mapping for "anagrafica"

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
the problem was in the form:action:

```
    action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/formazione/save"
```

has to be

```
    action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/anagrafica/save"
```

and into the controller I put

```
    redirect:/formazione
```

as ScanQR suggested. Thanks a lot